# Geometrical structure factor

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I was reading about the geometrical structure factor whose equation is:

[image]

when determining the structure factor of a simple cubic shell in this book (the picture is down below) they simply assumed that the total number of atom in the cubic cell is 1 (which is true) and that 1 atom is in the origin( i.e. $u=v=w=0$). now I am not able to warp my head round the fact that why the atom must need to be in the origin (if we assume that it's not in the origin the the structure factor would change since the u,v,w term will not be equal to zero). so what is the reason behind choosing the position of that atom to be in the origin.

[image]